# How to change what xdg-open does with ssh://user@ip liniks

Tags: ssh, url

xdg open has ignored my directives.  I have found several threads regarding how to open ssh://user@ip links (these are in our monitoring software).  I have run the following commands:

```
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/command '/home/dankney/bin/SSH.handler %s' --type String
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/enabled --type Boolean true
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/needs_terminal --type Boolean true
```

Yet still when I attempt to use xdg-open (as the chrome browser does) it attempts to sftp instead...

```
xdg-open ssh://root@1.2.3.4
gvfs-open: sftp://root@1.2.3.4/: error opening location: The specified location is not mounted
```

It seems to be set correctly in the registery thingy

```
gconftool-2 -a /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh
 command = /home/dankney/bin/SSH.handler %s
 needs_terminal = true
 enabled = true
```

Oh - here is the ls -alFh and contents of SSH.handler

```
ls -alFh /home/dankney/bin/SSH.handler 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dankney dankney 133 Sep 18 21:16 /home/dankney/bin/SSH.handler*


cat /home/dankney/bin/SSH.handler*
#!/bin/bash
url=$1
protocol=${url//:*/}
machine=${url//*:\/\//}
machine=${machine%/}
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e "$protocol $machine"
```

what gives?

Oh - btw - the shell script indeed does work if run from command line...

Answer (score 5):

For any other late comers, with more recent versions of this issue - This link was the total solution for me: https://lithostech.com/2014/04/get-ssh-protocol-links-working-in-ubuntuchromeunity/

Basically, execute the following in a shell to create and reassign the ssh handler and mime type:

```
xdg-mime default ssh.desktop x-scheme-handler/ssh
cat << EOF > ~/.local/share/applications/ssh.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=SSH Launcher
Exec=bash -c '(URL="%U" HOST="\${URL:6}"; ssh \$HOST); bash'
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=utilities-terminal
EOF
```

Comment: I had to remove the escaping before `$` to make it work, but otherwise all good on Fedora 29 here!

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to change what `xdg-open` does with `ssh://` links, to replace konsole with yakuake as handler. And this is what I did on my Kubuntu 15.10 (KDE Frameworks 5.15.0):

1. found out what's the handler:

   ```
   $ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/ssh
   ktelnetservice5.desktop
   ```
2. located the handler on the disk:

   ```
   $ locate ktelnetservice5.desktop
   /usr/share/app-install/desktop/kio:ktelnetservice5.desktop
   /usr/share/applications/ktelnetservice5.desktop
   ```

   in my case I had to edit `/usr/share/applications/ktelnetservice5.desktop`
3. edited the handler replacing

   ```
   Exec=ktelnetservice5 %u
   ```

   with

   ```
   Exec=/path/to/some/script.sh %u
   ```

where that script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/window toggleWindowState; qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/sessions addSession && qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/sessions runCommand "ssh `echo $1 | cut -d'/' -f3`"
```

and was given execute privileges:

```
chmod +x /path/to/some/script.sh
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 1):

First you should set up a protocol handler, like this:

```
xdg-mime default ssh.desktop x-scheme-handler/ssh
```

Then make a desktop entry file and put it somewhere like `/usr/share/applications` (perhaps it would be better to put it somewhere in `~/.config`, though not sure where).

**ssh.desktop**:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Exec=/home/dankney/bin/SSH.handler %F
```

Then next time `xdg-open` is called, it will use the ssh.desktop handler, which in turn will delegate the call to your shell script.

Answer (score 0):

wrote a script support this url scheme:

```
ssh://[user[:pass]@]host[:port]
```

xdg-open-ssh:

use `gnome-terminal` or `terminator` open the ssh url,
  if `pass` occur, use `sshpass` input password.
     if `pass` err, failback to user input password.

https://github.com/yurenchen000/xdg-open-ssh